# Why azure throws this error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've upgraded EntityFramework from 4.1 to  5 and Upgraded .NET Framework to 4.5 on local machine everything works perfectly, but when I published my changes on Azure I receive this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your project references for that assembly.  Ensure that you have copy local set to true on the properties of that reference.  Also, upgrading your Azure SDK and EF may have impacted the versions of the assemblies referenced by the project.  Ensure that you have the correct versions referenced in your project as well.

Found what would potentially be the source of your issue -> especially if you are upgrading your project:  http://ivarunsingh.blogspot.com/2011/12/microsoftbuildutilitiesv35-report.html

Comment: I don't reference this assebly at all: Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5

Comment: Are you using the Report viewer in your project anywhere?

Comment: It comes down to something you are referencing needs that assembly.  It works on your local machine because it is in your GAC.  You will either need to add the reference to your project with copy local = true or find what component you are using references that assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying to a Windows Server 2012 image (I see that you are using .NET 4.5)? If you use the Azure SDK 1.8 and OSVersion = 3 (default for new cloud service projects on the new SDK)...

Windows Server 2012 does not have .NET 3.5 libraries enabled, you have to enable that feature (and I believe install it).  You may have to automate the enabling of the .NET 3.5.